# Default Export: Error en codigo de react en el import y el export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, module.exports

tengo el siguiente error en mi aplicación de react y no se como resolverlo:

> Compiled with problems:X

> ERROR in ./src/App/index.js 29:29-44

> Can't import the named export 'useLocalStorage' (imported as 'useLocalStorage') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

> ERROR in ./src/App/index.js 90:10-25

> Can't import the named export 'useLocalStorage' (imported as 'useLocalStorage') from default-exporting module (only default export is available)

en mi codigo estoy exportando e importando de la siguiente manera:

```
export { useLocalStorage };

import { useLocalStorage } from './useLocalStorage';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> only default export is available

Esto significa que donde quiera que tengas el componente `useLocalStorage` debes exportarlo como default:

```
//pseudocodigo
function useLocalStorage(){
   ...
   return ...
}

export default useLocalStorage;
```

Y luego para consumirlo debes hacerlo sin curly braces:

```
import useLocalStorage from './useLocalStorage';
```